# Terminal displays strange characters instead of prompt after upgrade from Xununtu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

I have just upgraded from Xubuntu 18.04 to Xubuntu 20.04.

When trying to use the terminal window (not the full-screen terminal) I only see strange characters.

[image: terminal with some lines. In one of them I entered "ls -l"]

The terminal window I am talking about is managed by xfce4-terminal version 0.8.9.1.

Under Xubuntu 18.04 my terminal prompt was colored. I guess, the escape sequences to make color output don't work any longer.

**What must I do that the terminal window works again as before.**

The full screen terminal, e.g. after **Ctl+Alt+F1**, is not affected. But that was not colored before either.

Although the display of the terminal is unreadable for me, it is operational.

The first comment suggested to enter a command to show its output. But the output is done int the strange way I am complaining about. However, I can divert the output to a file and that is readable (in mousepad). So I issued the command `echo "$PS1" | od -bc > t.txt` . The content from the resulting output file is:

`0000000 134 133 134 145 135 060 073 134 165 100 134 150 072 040 134 167`

`\   [   \   e   ]   0   ;   \   u   @   \   h   :       \   w`

`0000020 134 141 134 135 044 173 144 145 142 151 141 156 137 143 150 162`

`\   a   \   ]   $   {   d   e   b   i   a   n   _   c   h   r`

`0000040 157 157 164 072 053 050 044 144 145 142 151 141 156 137 143 150`

`o   o   t   :   +   (   $   d   e   b   i   a   n   _   c   h`

`0000060 162 157 157 164 051 175 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060 061 073`

`r   o   o   t   )   }   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0   1   ;`

`0000100 063 062 155 134 135 134 165 100 134 150 134 133 134 060 063 063`

`3   2   m   \   ]   \   u   @   \   h   \   [   \   0   3   3`

`0000120 133 060 060 155 134 135 072 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060 061`

`[   0   0   m   \   ]   :   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0   1`

`0000140 073 063 064 155 134 135 134 167 134 133 134 060 063 063 133 060`

`;   3   4   m   \   ]   \   w   \   [   \   0   3   3   [   0`

`0000160 060 155 134 135 134 044 040 012`

`0   m   \   ]   \   $      \n`

`0000170`

(unfortunately I could not use block quote here: it would have garbeled it all such that the correspondence between the lines can not be seen any more).

Comment: Examine `$PS1`, the prompt string (read `man bash`). Do `echo "$PS1" | od -bc`. Usually set up in `~/.bashrc` or one of the other startup files (again, `man bash`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your `~/.cache/fontconfig` and generate the fontcache again:

```
rm -rf ~/.cache/fontconfig
fc-cache -r -v
```

That most likely will help. If not, there is a problem with the systemwide installed font files.

- Check in the terminal preferences what font is in use for the terminal
- Purge and reinstall that font, or try a different font

Actually, after an upgrade, do not hesitate to fully wipe the `~/.cache` folder. It is cache, i.e., files aimed for speedier loading, and will be recreated as you continue to use the updated system.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your suggestions and removed ~/.cache completely. That did not do the job. Not even after reboot. Your hint with the first bullet point was the right one for my problem: In the preferences I saw "no font" predefined. After setting it to "Free Mono Standard" the maze was gone. Thank you!

Comment: Another user's account gave me the opportunity to look if setting the font of xfce4-terminat to "Free Mono Standard" alone will do it: Yes, this was the case. - The question remains how to prevent someone else from tripping over such a molehill: **How can such a thing happen? Where should I submit an error message?**

Comment: That is "upgrade pain". Never guaranteed to be flawless. Advise: do a fresh install each time. That said, I also do not do that anymore because I have way too much customizations ;) Anyway, for xfce this particular transition, from 18.04 to 20.04, that means for xfce, from GTK2 to GTK3 might have been an extra peculiarity for the upgrade process. Technically, "where to submit an error message" is a different question. Feel free to ask it, but I would guess: Ubuntu launchpad.